# Trouble getting images to display at random positions using javaScript

Tags: javascript, css, random

I am trying to generate 5 images on the left-hand side of the page in random positions. The images are displayed in a row across the top and not in the random positions that I require. I do have img{position:absolute} within my CSS. I am sorry if this has been covered previously, I have searched endlessly for an answer and tried many different examples, but I am still stuck, can someone point me in the right direction, please.

```
<script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");

    function getRandom(x, y) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (y - x)) + x + 'px';
    };

    function generateFaces() {
      for (var i=0; i<numberOfFaces; i++) {
        var faces = document.createElement("img");
        faces.src = "smile.png";
        faces.style.top = getRandom(0, 400);
        faces.style.left = getRandom(0, 400);
        leftSide.appendChild(faces);
      };
    };

    </script>
```

Comment: hey can you just make a working demo on jsfiddle of your code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pynaam1f/

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/pynaam1f/1/

```
img{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Sorry all new to me, here is my jfiddle:

Comment: I have now however fixed the problem, this has taken me days and it was just a mis-spelling on img{} in my CSS, gutted that I didn't notice the problem sooner, but I think I have learnt a lot in the process of it. Many thanks for trying to help, much appreciated. :-)